# localStorage doesn't refresh the grid

Tags: jquery, grid, local-storage, kendo-ui

I can't solve this problem.

Here is my code

```
var selectedID = "";
    var selectedIDPremise = "";
    var PremisesGrid = "";
    var PremisesGrid2 = "";
    var selectedIDPremise2 = "";
    //var selectedOD2 = "";
    var nova = "";

    $(document).ready(function () {



        $("#routes").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "Id",
            dataSource: {
                type: "application/jsonp",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://" + servername + "/uBillingServices/Administration/Administration.svc/getRoute",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            ID: 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            select: onSelect
        });

        //nova = PremisesGrid2.getKendoDropDownList().dataSource.transport.options.read.data.Route_ID;

        function onSelect(e) {

            //$.getJSON("http://" + servername + "/uBillingServices/Administration/Administration.svc/getRoute", { ID: nova }, function (json) { });
            window.localStorage.setItem("Nova", "");
            nova = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
            window.localStorage.setItem("Nova", nova.ID);
            PremisesGrid2.getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
            //nova = PremisesGrid2.getKendoDropDownList().dataSource.transport.options.read.data.Route_ID;
            // var data = [{}];
            //PremisesGrid2.getKendoGrid().dataSource.data(data)
            for (var i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
                if (i == 2999) {
                    PremisesGrid2.getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
                }
            }

        }
            PremisesGrid2 = $("#assignedRoute").kendoGrid({
                //dataTextField: "Name",
                //dataValueField: "Id",
                dataSource: {
                    type: "application/jsonp",
                    transport: {
                        read:
                                {
                                    url: "http://" + servername + "/uBillingServices/Premise/Premise.svc/GetAllPremisesByRoute",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: {
                                        Route_ID: window.localStorage.getItem("Nova"),
                                        UserName: userName,
                                        WorkStation: workStation

                                    }
                                }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                ID: { type: "string" },
                                PostalCode: { type: "string" },
                                Latitude: { type: "string" },
                                Longitude: { type: "string" },
                                IsMember: { type: "string" }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                change: function (arg) {

                    myIndex = this.select().index();
                    var PremisesRow = this.select();

                },
                dataBound: function (e) {

                    row = e.sender.tbody.find(">tr:not(.k-grouping-row)").eq(0);
                    if (row.length == 0) {
                        e.sender.select(e.sender.tbody.find(">tr:first"));
                    }
                    else {
                        e.sender.select(row);
                    }
                },
                selectable: true,
                scrollable: true,
                filterable: true,
                groupable: false,
                sortable: {
                    mode: "single",
                    allowUnsort: false
                },
                height: 330,

                columns: [
                    { field: "PostalCode", title: "Assigned Route" }
                    ]//, width: "100px"
            });
```

the localStorage is working fine(in resources it changes), but it doesn't refresh the grid when I select another Reon (form the DropDown list),and when I refresh the page it shows the last one I selected

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Please make a fiddle or link to the orginal. I dont even understand whats the Problem, and not willing to read the whole code to may understand it.

Comment: I hope this will help, so you can help me :)

http://jsfiddle.net/WxCZf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of questions:

1. Confusion between `ID` and `Id`.
2. `data` definition in `transport.read.data` needs to be a function.

Regarding 1. In the `DropDownList` definition you say `dataValueField: "Id"` but in `onSelect` you use: `window.localStorage.setItem("Nova", nova.ID);`

Regarding 2. Change the definition of `data` from `object` to `function`. This way:

```
data    : function () {
    return {
        {
            Route_ID: window.localStorage.getItem("Nova"),
            UserName: userName,
            WorkStation: workStation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed everything you said and still does nothing. On the first load it fills the grid with the datasource of the last choosen window.localStorage.getItem("Nova")

When I look in developer tools / Resources the value of "Nova" changes when I change it in the DropDown, but it doesnt refresh the grid...and when I refresh the whole page, the data source od the grid is with the datasource of the last choosen item form DropDownList

Comment: Did you check if the `DataSource.read()` is actually sending the request to the server? Add in the `data` function a trace showing that `window.localStorage.getItem("Nova");` actually has the `Id` of the `dropDownList`. Finally you can try disabling `cache` in `transport.read` making sure that KendoUI sends the request. One last thing, which version of KendoUI are you using.

Comment: it WORKS :))) there where extra {} in the function :)

There is only one problem left. When I refresh the page the dropdown changes (it shows the first item), but the grid datasource is from the last item

Comment: What was finally the problem?

Comment: Did you realize that in the `DropDownList` you are also sending in `data` `ID` and not `Id`. Where do you load saved `Id` for loading initial option of the `DropDownList`?

Comment: Do you know why (or how to do it) when I select form the DorpDown if the dataSource is empty it doesn't show a ampty grid, but the last one that is not empty?

Comment: Could you check if the request is being sent to the server? Try disabling the cache by putting transport.read.cache:false this forces sending the request to the server no matter kendo believes it is the same of the last request.